# A strange behavior when releasing gas pedal in neutral

Tags: engine, toyota, fjcruiser

I've bought a new Toyota FJ Cruiser about 6 months ago. Since the early months I accidentally noticed that right after I rev-up my car engine to more than 3000 rpm in neutral or P gears and release the gas pedal completely, the rpm (on the way down), jerks (a single hit) at about 2000 rpm. The car engine sounds completely normal, the power of the car and acceleration is excellent and I even showed this to Toyota service but they said this is normal. For me, this is not because, once during off-roading, this behavior was completely gone! Again the car acceleration, power and idle engine sound is perfect. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: @user38183 They said if there was any issue with either of these the engine check light would be turned on.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The "best" way to see if this is normal would be to test drive another vehicle just like yours and see if it does the same thing. While it may be a bit *weird*, I don't think it's anything to worry about.